# Problem with ln expression and integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

For $\displaystyle\int{\frac{1}{x\ln x\sqrt{\ln^2x-1}}}dx$,

- I first applied a $u$-sub. $u = \ln x$ -> $\displaystyle du = \frac{1}{x}dx$
- the integral then become $\displaystyle\int{\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}}du$
- This is the directly integral formula or $arcsec(x)$, as a result, the result is $\text{arcsec}(u)+C$ -> $\text{arcsec}(\ln x)+C$

However, I used the online calculator, they found the result of $\arctan(\sqrt{\ln^2x-1})+C$. And I used the function "Check my answer", they say what I found is not correct!

Can anybody tell me where I made a mistake? I couldn't see the mistake even trying to take the derivate of $\text{arcsec}(\ln x)$!

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Comment: But my answer is $\text{arcsec}\ln x$ and the calculator got the answer $\text{arctan}\sqrt{\ln x^2 - 1}$. I never used $\text{arcsin}x $

Comment: Sorry, I read $\arcsin$ instead of ${\rm arc\, sec}$

Comment: No worries, but I just don't know where I did wrong? Because the steps that calculators showed to get arctan is reasonable as well, but I can't see any mistakes in my steps neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inverse trig functions can always be thought of as angles.  Let $\theta = \mbox{arcsec } x.$   Then $\sec \theta = x.$  If you draw a triangle showing this it would have hypotenuse of length $x$ and adjacent leg of length $1$.  So the opposite side is $\sqrt{x^2-1}$.  Then

$$\tan \theta  = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{1}$$

or

$$\theta = \arctan \sqrt{x^2-1}.$$

So your answer is correct.   One trick, as long as you have your online calculator up and running, is that you could plot both answers together and see if they differ only by a constant.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much! I didn't know that it is possible to differ by a constant as it is always C for me!

Comment: But would you mind telling me why the image of $\text{arctan} \sqrt{\ln^2 x -1}$ has one part from $(0, \displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2})$ going to axis, while that of $\text{arcsec} \sqrt{\ln x }$ goes from the same point but upwards? (While the other part of the graph actually matches)

Comment: The domain for $\sec x$  has to be restricted so that the function is $1-1$ before we can define the inverse.  Not all authors restrict the domain the same.  And probably in your specific case, the function is jumping to a different "branch" of $\mbox{arcsec}.$

Comment: This is what I get after entering the two functions [image link](https://ibb.co/ypMD2CL). So which part should I verify to know is my answer is correct?

Comment: If you graph the two separately, you'll see they coincide on the piece to the right.  The pieces near the origin are problematic.  Near $0$, $\ln x$ is negative.   This is squared (and made positive) in one function but not in the other, so there's some sort of interference from the square root function.  Very icky.

Comment: Actually, if you replace the unsquared $\ln x$ with $\sqrt{\ln(x)^2}$ the graphs are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\tan \alpha=\sqrt{\sec^2 \alpha -1}
$$

---

this means that the two solutions seems to be the same, but there is difference in the domain of the two functions:

$arcsec(\log x)$ is defined for $\log x \ge 1$

$\arctan\sqrt{\log^2 x -1}$ is defined for $\log^2 x-1 \ge 0$

since your starting function is defined for $\log^2 x-1 > 0$, the correct integral, on the almost full domain of the starting function is the second one.

Comment: There is a difference in the domain of the two functions. can you see ?

Comment: I added something to my answer.

Comment: Yes, now I can see. Thank you very much for pointing out, I wasn't focusing on that. I was just trying to find the derivative